# RewriteRule [E=CONTENT_TYPE:foo/bar] has no effect on Apache/mod_php

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, cgi

I was [trying to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5561078/userland-multipart-form-data-handler) prevent PHP from parsing POST requests. It does automatically when it sees the according MIME type. For that I was considering following RewriteRule hack:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Content-Type} ^(multipart/form-data\s*;.*)$   
RewriteRule mime.php - [E=CONTENT_TYPE:no/parsing;old=%1]
```

But the CGI environment still contains the original `[CONTENT_TYPE] => multipart/form..`

- I could set e.g. ALT_CONTENT_TYPE troublefree, but that's no use to me, because PHP still acts on the original then.
- Likewise changing the case `[E=ContEnt_Type]` will not remove the old header value, it just changes the case really.
- Is the CONTENT_TYPE env var constructed at a later stage? Because I also had trouble accessing it as just %{CONTENT_TYPE}. But on a second look, the docs http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond didn't mention it anyway.

Is there another way to override this CGI variable?

#### local testserver:

```
 Server version: Apache/2.2.14 (Ubuntu)
 mod_php, not fastcgi
 Linux snig 2.6.32-29-generic #58-Ubuntu SMP, 2011 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1361673/get-raw-post-data/1361696#1361696) suggests an Apache solution:

```
<Location "/backend/XXX.php">
    SetEnvIf Content-Type ^(multipart/form-data)(.*) NEW_CONTENT_TYPE=multipart/form-data-alternate$2 OLD_CONTENT_TYPE=$1$2
    RequestHeader set Content-Type %{NEW_CONTENT_TYPE}e env=NEW_CONTENT_TYPE
</Location>
```

Comment: That works. Needs an `a2enmod headers` though. So maybe not workable on all servers. (But the existence of that specific module makes a simpler solution unlikely.)

Comment: Rewriting may require an `a2enmod rewrite`, so it's no more or less workable on principle.